# Meaning of "as when" in this context

Tags: meaning

What does "as when" mean here? I didn't get the meaning.

▪Luck played a role, **as when** cut-price DVD players debuted just in time for Christmas in 2001, months after the dotcom crash forced Mr Hastings to lay off a third of his 120-odd workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of words elided because they’re obvious from context to a native English speaker. Is it clearer as: “Luck played a role, as **it did** when cut-price DVD players debuted...”?